# Set Programmatically scale and scroll (ImageView)

Tags: android, imageview

I couldn't find anything that work.

How can i set the Scale(x and y) and scroll(x and y) of an ImageView Programmatically?

Comment: `setImageMatrix()` when `android:scaleType="matrix"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType scaleType)` to control and resize your image inside an imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It must help

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.xml_name_layout);

final ImageView switcherView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img);

switcherView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {

        float curX, curY;

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mx = event.getX();
                my = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                curX = event.getX();
                curY = event.getY();
                switcherView.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                mx = curX;
                my = curY;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                curX = event.getX();
                curY = event.getY();
                switcherView.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
  });
}
```